# Why script run only 1 time?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote this code so that when I press on the image this image changes color. The problem is that click works only once; when I click a second time, nothing happens. Why?

```
immagine1 = Label(root, image=photo1)
immagine1.place(x=20, y=20)

def su1(event):
    print ("coordinate 1", event.x, event.y)
    clickX1 = event.x
    clickY1 = event.y
    if (clickX1 >= 10 and clickX1 <= 275 and clickY1 >= 10 and clickY1 <= 320):
        immagine1 = Label(root, image=photo2)
        immagine1.place(x=20, y=20)

def giu1(event):
    clickX1 = event.x
    clickY1 = event.y
    if (clickX1 >= 10 and clickX1 <= 275 and clickY1 >= 10 and clickY1 <= 320):
        immagine1 = Label(root, image=photo1)
        immagine1.place(x=20, y=20)

immagine1.bind("<Button-1>", su1)
immagine1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", giu1)
```

Correct:

```
immagine1 = Label(root, image=photo1)
immagine1.place(x=20, y=20)

def su1(event):
    print ("coordinate 1", event.x, event.y)
    clickX1 = event.x
    clickY1 = event.y
    if (clickX1 >= 10 and clickX1 <= 275 and clickY1 >= 10 and clickY1 <= 320):
        immagine1.configure(image=photo2)

def giu1(event):
    clickX1 = event.x
    clickY1 = event.y
    if (clickX1 >= 10 and clickX1 <= 275 and clickY1 >= 10 and clickY1 <= 320):
        immagine1.configure(image=photo1)

immagine1.bind("<Button-1>", su1)
immagine1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", giu1)
```

Comment: Because you are reassigning `immagine1` to a new `Label` object in your functions. This object hasn't been bound to your event handlers

Comment: how do you know it doesn't work second time ? Do you get error when you run it ?  always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be this line:

```
immagine1 = Label(root, image=photo2)
```

Here you're re-assigning the `immagine1` variable and therefore you're losing the bind that you did:

```
immagine1.bind("<Button-1>", su1)
```

Comment: Many thanks to all, I modified the code and now it works well.